# iOS update application automatically

Tags: ios, auto-update

Is it possible to automatically update application without user interference? I read that in iOS 7, all apps will automatically update without users having to take any actions. What about iOS prior to iOS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All application updates are handled by the Mac App store. The change from iOS 6 to 7 is that it will automatically update the applications during night time when the iOS device is charging and on WiFi, without the user having to press the "update all" button in the update section of the Mac App Store!

Thus the user will not have to get involved to keep his/her applications up to date.

And this change will most likely not be included iOS prior to 7!